# Geometric interpretation of $S_1 \times \mathbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

what does $S_1 \times \mathbb Z$ represent?

I don't think this is a cylinder and  I think $S_1 \times \mathbb R$ is a cylinder.

Is this right?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It represents an infinite number of parallel circles indexed by the integers (each one unit apart).

Comment: yes, i could imagine. it is not a cylinder. isn't it?

Comment: Right not a cylinder, but it's slices in the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

I might see $S_1 \times \mathbb{R}$ as a cylinder going off forever in either direction, and $S_1 \times \mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of said cylinder consisting of a set of equally spaced rings.